# What is TSQL TinyInt in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm puzzled as to what cast in C# to make for a query to T-SQL that returns a `tinyint`.

Using a `SqlDataReader`...

```
int Precision = 0;

SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
   Precision = reader.GetInt16(0);
}
```

I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` when I use `GetInt16`, and that's the smallest integer cast apparently available. In the same code I successfully cast a `smallint` to `int16`.

What `Get....` do I use for `tinyint`?

**Edited to add:**

An answer which was subsequently deleted said to use `GetByte`. I did, and that worked.

Comment: I knew this had to have been answered already, but a search of SO didn't yield the question that @CodeCaster indicated as a prior question -- and the question itself didn't either.  I thank everyone who answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947(v=vs.110).aspx)", it is `short` when you are mapping from SQL to CLR.

Comment: The documentation says TINYINT maps to System.Int16. But the code above does not work. On the other hand, GetByte *does* work.

Comment: Ok, In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) documentation stated that `tinyint` maps to `byte` which is more suitable in your case because AOD.NET on the scene. (the above mentioned doc related to LINQ2SQL).

Comment: That's fine, then.  Thanks!  The duplicate question has a nice table to it, also.